# What does ./ mean?

Tags: files, rm

I'm having a hard time getting what `./` does.

In the Linux Essentials books, it asks me in an exercise to delete a file named `-file`. After googling, I found that I need to do `rm ./-file` but I don't get why!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.` directory is the current directory. The directory `..` is the upper level of that directory

```
$ pwd
/home/user

$ cd docs; pwd   # change to directory 'docs'
/home/user/docs

$ cd .  ; pwd     # we change to the '.' directory, therefore we'll stay. No change
/home/user/docs

$ cd .. ; pwd     # back to up level
/home/user
```

In Linux, commands options are introduced by the `-` sign, i.e., `ls -l`, so if you want to make any reference to a file beginning with `-` such as `-file`, the command would think you are trying to specify an option. For example, if you want to remove it:

```
rm -file
```

will complain because it's trying to use the option `file` of the command `rm`. In this case you need to indicate where the file is. Being in the current directory, thus the `.` directory, you need to refer to that file as `./-file`, meaning, in the directory `.`, the file `-file`. In this case the command `rm` won't think that's an option.

```
rm ./-file
```

It can be done, also, using `--`.

From `man rm`:

> To  remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
>   one of these commands:
>
> ```
> rm -- -foo
> rm ./-foo
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you type `rm -file` you will be passing a commandline option to `rm` not the name `-file`.

To delete `-file` pass `rm` the name in quotes `rm "-file"` or escape the `-`. `rm \\-file`.
In either bash or zsh if you are unsure that a command is getting the proper filename use tab completion. Examples: `type rm -fi`<kbd>TAB</kbd> if the screen does not printout `rm -file` you know you did something wrong and should fix it before hitting return, another example `rm "-fi`<kbd>TAB</kbd> should printout `rm "-file"`.

As for `./`, `/` is just the separator between directories and filenames. "." means present directory. ".." means the directory one up. So to delete the file `foo` in the present directory type `rm ./foo` ( `rm foo` is OK too ) to delete the file one directory up type `rm ../foo` to delete the file in the directory `bar` which is contained in the directory above type `rm ../bar/foo`.

In this case `./` is put in front of `-file` so that the `-` character is not the first thing that `rm` sees because that would make it think you are using some option.

If you know a bit of DOS, `rm -file` would correspond to `rm /file` in DOS.

Answer (score 0):

. is the current directory. So e.g. `ls` and `ls .` are synonymous. If you are in `/etc` the commands `cat /etc/fstab/`, `cat ./fstab` and `cat fstab` do the same thing.

`rm ./-file` is used because `rm` parses everything starting with `-` as command line options and not file names. For example `ls -l` does not try to show file named `-l`, but `ls ./-l` and `ls /some/directory/-l` do.